# Extract System date and enter it using selenium automation using tcl script

Tags: selenium, tcl

i am using Cisco call manger , i am able to automate all the pages but i need to put system date in one of the field using selenium through tcl script

in the text field i need to input system date in YYYY:MM:DD:HH format

Comment: I'm not sure if DateTime.Now exists in the tool you are suing But in general we have something like 'DateTime.Now' in c# which returns the system date. See if you have something similar

Answer (score 2):

In Tcl, [the `clock` command](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/clock.htm) is used to work with timestamps. In particular, `clock seconds` gets the current Unix epoch instant, and `clock format` can be used to transform such instants into human-readable form (with a suitable format string).

```
clock format [clock seconds] -format "%Y:%m:%d:%H"
```

The `%Y` means “four digit year”, the `%m` means “two digit month”, the `%d` means “two digit day-of-month” and the `%H` means “two digit hour in 24-hour clock”.